# How to install a swift library consisting just of swift files

Tags: xcode, swift, ios7

Suppose I have a swift library that consists of a large folder with subfolders with subfolders all containing many .swift files I would like my .swift project to be aware of - just as if I had written all that code myself.

My swift project targets ios7+ meaning there are some issues with various package systems - and the given library I am trying to add acually suggests using the above method.

Currenly I have "attached" the swift-library-folder next to my own .swift files and during this I checked all targets.

Interestingly, I can not change/add targets for any of the files in the folder since the option does not show itself when clicking the .swift files in xcode (**!**)

Anyhow, when trying to use one of the classes defined in he swift-library, xcode does not recognize it.

What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are they added to your project? Are you telling Xcode to build them?

Comment: I have added a screenshot now. Not sure if there is anything else I can do to tell Xcode to build them? Am I missing something? But it is curious that I can not change "target membership" for the files, so could look like I still need to do something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you dragg the *folder* containing these files into Xcode, rather than the individual files. That was the first issue, since that sort of thing has a special meaning. Then, you saw a dialog like this:

[image]

I'm not sure what you did at that moment, but I don't think your settings looked like mine! They need to. Delete the files and perform this import again.

For best results, select just the *Swift files* in the Finder and drag them into Xcode this time. (You can drag them all at once, in one move; but drag the files, not a folder.) But if you can't do that, make sure you are creating groups — *not* folder references.

Comment: I appears it works better when I add the files as you propose. I used folder references (but where the files are placed in he project folder)  - I am currently getting another error in the library now (ios-charts) but I *think* that is unrelated, so I believe i will accept the answer soon :) (upvoted for now)