# xcode 8.2.1 (with swift) not loading external files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a little problem with xcode. I've already seen this question/problem but the answers couldn't help me this time (yes, I've had this problem in the past).

So my problem is, that xcode is not loading my images/external files while testing/running the app.

If I put my images in xcode without folder, so just the images, it loads. But when I put them in a folder (and some sub-folders) , xcode can't find the images anymore when I'm running the app (in the storyboard it can finds them).

I've already cleaned the app and re imported the images.

Also it isn't a problem with just 1 project, if I start an all new fresh project, I have the same problem.

I hope I've explained my problem enough, if there are questions, I'll be more than happy to answer those.

Also if you can help me out, I will be thankful forever! This problem is really slowing down the development of our app.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Can you show the project structure and the codes/configurations loading the images?

Comment: If the folder is a folder reference, so that it is copied wholesale into the your app bundle, you have to dive into it explicitly. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42537723/341994

Comment: @aahung it's just a fresh installed xcode, new project, so no special configurations.

Comment: @matt I'll have a look, thank you !

Comment: also, I always could have folders with images. It's only since I've bought a new macbook pro touchbar version last week that I have this problem.

Comment: @MaximVanWalleghem That means you are failing to notice that you are making folder references. When you drag the folder into Xcode, a dialog appears. Look carefully at that dialog! If the second option is chosen (folder references), you are going to have this problem. You want a _group_, not a folder reference. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35785609/341994

Comment: But basically my response is: well, don't do that! If you want these image files to be readily available, don't drag a folder into Xcode at all: drag the _files_! Even better, use the asset catalog; that's what it's for.

Comment: yes, you're right, this problem only happens when I chose for folder references instead of groups. It's weird because in the past I always could do this... But now it's fixed. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the images into the `.xcassets` folder where your AppIcon is. Also, add files individually into the `.xcassets` and not drag a whole folder of images into the project.

Sorry for the short answer but you could add more information to the question like images of your folder structure and how you call the image